# What is the best way to connect 2 DC with VXLAN?

Tags: vxlan, evpn

If I have 2 standard VxLAN Spine-Leaf setup, what would be the best way to create 1 VXLAN segment out of the 2 DC?
I have 2 WAN links between the Data Centers to interconnect them.
[image]

Comment: What are your options? I wouldn't use the leaves as VTEPs as that very much complicates things. Just use your spine switches as VTEPs and create two tunnels between them. You might want to use MSTP or similar to split VLAN traffic across them, depending on your WAN connectivity.

Comment: `1 VXLAN segment`  Do you mean one single  VXLAN/EVPN fabric?   Also: Are your leaf switches single units or some MLAG capable pair? (such as Cisco vPC)?

Comment: All leaf switches are single units and I want to achieve a single VXLAN segment. 
I made a setup where the switch Loopback addresses are advertised via eBGP connections (except DC1 Spine1 <-iBGP-> DC2 Spine1 AND DC1 Spine2 <-iBGP-> DC2 Spine2). As of the "overlay", MAC address advertisements are going through a single iBGP segment where DC1 Spine1 and DC2 Spine2 are the Route Reflectors. 
What do you think about that?
Technically it works.